# Notepad++ Open containing folder and SELECT FILE

Tags: notepad++

What should I add to the following command (in shortcuts.xml) so that Notepad++ would open the containing folder and also select the current file?

`<Command name="Open containing folder" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">explorer $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)</Command>`

Thank you.

Comment: The following command opens the folder and selects the file. I'm still looking for a way to open the folder maximized.


&quot;C:\Windows\Explorer.exe&quot; /select, &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;


Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find it in my Notepad++ v6.6.9. working out-of-the-box:

1. Right-click tab of desired document.
2. From context menu, select **Open Containing Folder in Explorer**.

   ▶ This command not only opens given folder, but also **selects current file**.
      In Notepad++ source code you can see that the menu command performs the same as yours:  
      `explorer /select,$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)` so you do not need to add it by yourself.
      And you can also check [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/789377/opening-current-directory-command-in-notepad) for the command line.

Comment: Thanks.
I wanted to select the file.

I use the following code: &quot;C:\Windows\nircmd.exe&quot; exec max &quot;C:\Windows\Explorer.exe&quot; /select, &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;

Comment: @Yaron - You didn't test steps given in the asnwer, did you? My apologies for not explicitly stating the result of the command. Now you can find it in the edited answer (last paragraph).

Comment: Thank you miroxlav. I appreciate your help.
It's been a while since I posted this question, and I apologize for not elaborating a bit more.
I use NP++ v6.4.5. More recent versions have some problems with RTL languages (e.g. Hebrew).
I also wanted the window to open maximized, and hence the use of nircmd.
If you have a better way, please let me know. I'd be grateful.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

Comment: @Yaron - I missed your point with maximized window, sorry for that. For such a purpose, nircmd does its job well.

Comment: Thanks again. It's kind of you.
I didn't mention the "maximized window" in the original question.
You didn't miss it. :) I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

From https://vincent.re/en/open-containing-folder-in-notepad

To assign the command to a shortcut. Open `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml` with an editor. In the `<Macros>` tag add the following for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

```
<Macro name="Open Containing Folder in Explorer" Ctrl="yes" Alt="no" Shift="yes" Key="79"> 
 <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="41019" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
</Macro>
```

So for example, my file will look like this after

```
<NotepadPlus>
    <InternalCommands />
    <Macros>
        <Macro …>…</Macro>
        <Macro name="Open Containing Folder in Explorer" Ctrl="yes" Alt="no" Shift="yes" Key="79"> 
            <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="41019" lParam="0" sParam="" /> 
        </Macro>        
    </Macros>
    <UserDefinedCommands>
        <Command…>…</Command>
    </UserDefinedCommands>
    <PluginCommands />
    <ScintillaKeys />
</NotepadPlus>
```