# Opening Current Directory Command in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm new to programming. I have a notepad++ but it doesn't have the "Open current dir cmd" in the run tab....Are there any alternatives for me to open my file notepad++ file in a command prompt? Please help me.... I have Windows 7 by the way if that's gonna do anything.

Comment: Set customized commands:- Click Run -> Run -> Browse button to 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe' -> Save -> Type name "Open current dir cmd", add shortcut or not and click OK this should place the commmand in the Run menu. 
You should be able to do this with any command or program you wish to add, i think.
Reff:- Notepad++ menu Click on ?(help), Click on Help contents, from the Document Navigator Click on Commands

Comment: SynWrite editor has similar command in Tools menu.

Answer (score 6):

In Notepad++ v6.6.9 this function is already present.

1. Right-click tab of desired document.
2. From context menu, select **Open Containing Folder in cmd**.
   The command launches the following: `cmd /K cd /d $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)` (This was taken from N++ source code.)

Similar question: [Open folder in Explorer and select current file](https://superuser.com/questions/775245/notepad-open-containing-folder-and-select-file)